# Double response from subscribe when I expect one

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a rather strange problem, which is when I subscribe to the latestMessageCollection - when I add a new document in Firestore - I get two responses. There should be one.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRooms();
    this.chatList.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      const dateA = new Date(a.lastMessage.date);
      const dateB = new Date(b.lastMessage.date);
      return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
    });
  }

  getRooms() {
    this.communicatorService.getRooms().subscribe((rooms) => {
      this.chatList = [];
      rooms.forEach((room, index, array) => {
        console.log(room.room);
        const latestMessageCollection = this.firestore.collection(`chat/rooms/${room.room}`, ref => ref
          .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
          .limit(1)
        )
          .valueChanges({idField: 'id'});
        latestMessageCollection.subscribe((latestMessage) => {
          console.log('CHANGE', index, latestMessage[0]);
          const lastMessage = latestMessage[0];
          if (!this.getChatByRoom(this.chatList, room.room)) {
            this.avatarsToLoad.push({
              room: room.room,
              avatar: room.sender.avatar
            });
            this.chatList.push({
              room: room.room,
              user: {
                id: room.sender.id,
                name: room.sender.name + ' ' + room.sender.lastname,
                avatar: room.sender.avatar,
                description: ''
              },
              lastMessage: {
                user: latestMessage.length !== 0 ? lastMessage.user : 0,
                content: latestMessage.length !== 0 ? lastMessage.message : '',
                date: latestMessage.length !== 0 ? lastMessage.createdAt.toDate() : new Date('0000-00-00 00:00')
              },
              unreadMessagesCount: 0
            });
          }
        });
        if (index === array.length - 1) {
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

console.log:
[image]

Here console.log should only happen once, not twice.

Someone can explain why this is so and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the problem here is that:

1. You might be running into the cache issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1728).
2. As per the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514628/angular-firestore-subscribe-fires-twice), it seems that debounceTime() might be a workaround.

Or else, you can check if you are having 2 living subscriptions at the same time.