# AngularFirestore update method causing observable to fire twice

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

In my angular project I am subscribed to a Firestore document like so:

```
const obs = this.db.collection('someCollection').doc('someDoc').valueChanges().subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

I am only subscribed in one place,
there is no async pipes in my template.

When I write directly to Firebase this works correctly, and I only receive one log.
When I use the set method from AngularFirebase I only receive one log.

```
this.db.collection('someCollection).doc('someDoc').set({value: 1});
//obs will log 'value:1'
```

But when I use the update method I get two logs.

```
this.db.collection('someCollection').doc('someDoc').update({value: 1});
//obs will log 'value:1' two times.
```

It seems to me that this should only log one time. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Firestore subscribe() fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514628/angular-firestore-subscribe-fires-twice)

Comment: No it doesn't. This question is both using a async pipe in the template and subscribing to the actual observable. So is subscribing twice. In the example I have asked about I have said that i'm not using a async pipe, and have only subscribed in one place.

Comment: found this github [thread1](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2728) & [thread2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2336) that might help

Comment: Have you checked the suggestions in above link.Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes helpful. Glad to know that i'm not alone. Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: can you provide the function where you are subscribing edit command so that we can confirm your also not calling valueSnapshot changes

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was that the value was optimistically updating locally (causing the observable to fire), then the value was being pushed to Firestore, and being reread causing the observable to fire again.

The way I figured this out was to turn off the network and the observable only fired once.

This also explains why, when I write directly to Firestore the observable only fires once.

So if you want the observable to only fire once, you have to put a distinctUntilChanged() function on the observable.